# Mesh.bounds and Renderer.bounds do not change when vertices are updated

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am growing a 3D model in size by adding the normal of each vertex to itself on each frame. The model clearly grows in size visually but when logging out the bounds they do not change.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class VertexExperiment : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Renderer renderer;

    void Start()
    {
        mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {

            Vector3 normal = vertices[i].normalized;
            vertices[i] = vertices[i] + normal;
        }
        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        print(renderer.bounds.size);
        print(mesh.bounds.size);
    }
}
```

Result of logging out values

[image: Result of logging]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to recalculate the bounds when you did a change in the vertices
Add this line before printing the bounds:

```
 mesh.RecalculateBounds();
```

Then you will see it will change. You can check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html) for more information. Good Luck with your experiment :)